# How to Download a File from OneDrive Using Vanilla JavaScript and MS Graph API

Tags: react-native, javascript, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, msal.js

I am trying to build a static web page using pure HTML CSS and JavaScript with the ability to download a file from OneDrive.

On button click event, a JavaScript function should access OneDrive and download Excel file for display on the browser without any user interactions or authentication.

As you know, making an AJAX call to the direct download link of the OneDrive file that looks something like this: *"https://onedrive.live.com/download?cid=32...&resid=32...&authkey=AD..."* throws Access to download link has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I tried [Using the OneDrive API in JavaScript apps (CORS support)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/concepts/working-with-cors?view=odsp-graph-online) example but that did not work.

I came across [HOW TO — Get an Access Token for Microsoft Graph API using Node.JS](https://askfiqri.com/how-to-get-an-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api-using-node-js-258723f29cc6). I followed the example and I was able to get the Access Token for authentication but this was only possible using Node.JS. I have searched the internet and almost all the example codes online use Node.JS to authenticate Microsoft Graph API.

- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/tree/dev/samples/browser
- https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-browser-samples/VanillaJSTestApp2.0

While others required user interaction for authentication which is not what I want.

See:  https://gist.github.com/psignoret/50e88652ae5cb6cc157c09857e3ba87f

My question is, using vanilla JavaScript (Not Node.JS), how can I

1. Log in to Microsoft Work, Office, or Personal Account.
2. Get the Access Token
3. Use the token and call Microsoft Graph to download a file from OneDrive

Without any user interaction/authentication?

Comment: How will your page be secured? You are making a UI that is to call secured Graph API without authentication? Will your page download files from just one user account or different user accounts?

Comment: My page is plain static and would be made to run on a private network. The page will download files from just one user account.

Comment: I still don't get how you will have a Vanilla JS page that downloads files without user interaction. At this point I can only suggest that you setup the app using msal.js to secure the page with a refresh token with reauthentication once in a while.